# Save data from spinner or Edit text based on selected item

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext, android-spinner

so i've got 13 items in spinner. I need to save data from spinner to SQLite database, it's not a problem BUT when i press the 13th item it means it will not save data from spinner but from edit text below. I will show you my code to be more specific.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if (position != 12 )
        {
            String hovno = (String) spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
            findViewById(R.id.editTextMaterial_A).setVisibility(editTextMaterial_A.GONE);
                          spinnerString = hovno;

        }
        if (position == 12)
        {
            String hovno = (String) spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Vybrano "+ hovno, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            findViewById(R.id.editTextMaterial_A).setVisibility(editTextMaterial_A.VISIBLE);



        }
    }
```

Like it will save values from spinner for all items except the 13th value, which will make edit text visible and save data from that edit text.
Have you got any ideas please? Like my problem is how to save the data to String called material_povrchuS.

Comment: can you explain your problem more clearly? if there are errors, please post the stacktrace

Comment: Yes ,my problem is that in this case it isn't saving data from spinner just from edit text, if i want to save data from spinner it's empty...

Comment: have you tried `String hovno = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();` or `String hovno = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();` ?

Comment: Yes, It's still not working. Edit text is ok, but spinner save empty record

Comment: what do you mean by "spinner save empty record"? have you successfully added the 13 items to the spinner? have you set the [listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) to the spinner?

Comment: if i want to save data from spinner it's save nothing. Spinner is ok. Problem must be in the if condition. Without that condition it works fine.